# \pounds and \textsterling produces a dollar sign?

Tags: symbols

I'm just trying to put a "£" sign in my document, but I can't get it to work.

My packages:

```
\usepackage[math]{iwona}         
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{listings}
```

`\pounds` and `\textsterling` both produce a dollar sign ("$").  I'm using `pdflatex`.

Comment: Both work for me, i.e produce £. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. And please don't reference your title in the body. Also "doesn't work" is not very meaningful. Do they really produce a $ sign?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As described in [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that/231#231) in such cases it is best to remove half of the used packages until the error disappears to track down the package which causes it.
In your case the error seems to be caused by the `iwona` font.
The wrong sign seems to be caused by the wrong font encoding. You should use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` together with `iwona` to avoid such things.

This works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[math]{iwona}
%\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}
%\usepackage{xspace}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
%\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{lscape}
%\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\pounds

\textsterling

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

`iwona` *does* have a `£` sterling sign.  (for example `0xbf` in the `t1` encoding
tables).  however, `£` sterling in `ot1` encoding is a booby-trap: in roman font,
the relevant character produces `$`, in italics it produces `£`.

i don't know what `iwona` thinks of as its default encoding, but i would expect
that `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` would solve the problem.

no doubt there are other encodings that will achieve this, but `t1` seems ok

Answer (score 2):

This has worked for me:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\textsterling
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command worked for me:

```
$\pounds$
```